# List hyphenated words on log

Tags: hyphenation, logging

I would like to review words that were hyphenated in a very long document. Looking at pdf output is too error prone. So I like to get a entry for every hyphenated word on compilation output or log file.

Reason: It's a good practice avoid bad hyphens. For example, in Portuguese: apóstolo = apostle, tolo = fool, so hyphenation após-tolo is a bad break, even if it is a gramatically correct break.

As an example, for a text typeset like this:

```
I would like to review
words that were hy-
phenated in a very long
document. Looking at
pdf output is too error
prone. So I like to get a
entry for every hyphen-
ated word on compila-
tion output or log file.
```

... I would like to get “`\typeout`” messages like:

```
HYPHEN: hy-phenated
HYPHEN: hyphen-ated
HYPHEN: compila-tion
```

I have searched a lot, no luck. I use pdflatex, babel package.

Comment: you could use luatex and iterate over the nodes to find hyphenated words in Lua. In pdftex/xetex that is not possible but if you use `\showoutput` the log gets a representation of the boxlevel output and a hyphen at the end of line shows as `-` followed by `\rightskip` so is easily found and with some editor scripting you could re-construct the hyphenated word list

Comment: Can I get some reference on why it is a "bad" hyphen?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks! A lot of regexp work (inside Emacs) but I managed to detect all hyphens. I found out that ```\hideoutput``` turns off ```\showoutput```.

Comment: anything is possible if you use emacs:-)

Comment: @BlackBird, I use the Brazilian book "Manual de Editoração e Estilo" by Plínio Martins Filho. I translate from page 445: You should not divide a word when in doing so it results in a ridiculous or inconvenient expression: após- / tolo, trans- / pirado, enros- / cadela, dis- / puta.  (n.b.: tolo=fool, pirado=fool [slang], cadela = bitch).

Comment: @MiguelV.S.Frasson, thank you for the reference. Then, it's a one-guy's touchy frisson about possible puns that only exist in his own childish head. I doubt anyone reading would bat an eyelid over that and stop to ponder. Nevertheless, one can see the pattern.